# Making a clustered bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, grouped-bar-chart

I have a little pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'Word': ['drink', 'cherry', 'berry', 'plum', 'crisp', 'spices'],
        'Percentage1': [18.166654, 13.498262, 9.810123, 7.964429, 7.892941, 0.856775],
        'Percentage2': [29.014272, 12.802642, 6.775552, 7.105845, 4.715009, 1.663586]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

     Word  Percentage1  Percentage2
0   drink    18.166654    29.014272
1  cherry    13.498262    12.802642
2   berry     9.810123     6.775552
3    plum     7.964429     7.105845
4   crisp     7.892941     4.715009
5  spices     0.856775     1.663586
```

Words (50) and the two columns with figures corresponding to every one of them signifying the incidence of the word.
How do I make a clustered chart to show the comparison of the two figures for each word?
I have tried virtually every piece of code that was offered to other people on this site, I just don't understand how to group the two "Percentage" columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can do in this way:

```
df.plot(x="Word", y=["Percentage1", "Percentage2"], kind="bar")
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

try this,

```
df.set_index('Word').plot(kind='bar')
```

O/P

[image]

If you don't want to perform chart for all the values columns in df use this. Just setting index act as `X` and rest of all the columns act as `y`

Input:

```
     Word  Percentage1  Percentage2  Percentage3  Percentage4
0   drink    18.166654    29.014272     7.105845    29.014272
1  cherry    13.498262    12.802642     4.715009    12.802642
2   berry     9.810123     6.775552     6.097997     3.408988
3    plum     7.964429     7.105845    12.802642    19.620618
4   crisp     7.892941     4.715009     6.775552    35.832248
```

O/P

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can choose stacked bar graph:

```
# Given
df = pd.DataFrame({'word':['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie'],
                  'Percentage 1':[10, 3, 0],
                  'Percentage 2': [5, 6, 4]})

df.set_index('word').plot(kind='barh', stacked=True)
```

[image: plt]

Answer (score 0):

- All of the existing options use `.set_index` and / or specify `y=`. However, the simplest solution is to only specify `x=` for the column to be on the x-axis.
- The only reason to specify `y=` is if there are many columns, and only selected columns are desired for plotting.
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.3`, `matplotlib 3.5.2`**

```py
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', x='Word', rot=0)
```

[image]